# onchange event to handle URL redirect and form submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the form submission because it is a simple

```
onchange="submit();"

                            <div class="cities">Select City <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" style="float:right;"><select name="city_select" id="city_select" onchange="submit();"><option>-----</option>
                        <option value="Beijing" <?php if($_SESSION['city_selected'] == 'Beijing') { echo 'selected=selected';} else { echo ''; }?> >Beijing</option>
                        <option value="Shanghai" <?php if($_SESSION['city_selected'] == 'Shanghai') { echo 'selected=selected';} else { echo ''; }?> >Shanghai</option>
                        <option value="Guangzhou" <?php if($_SESSION['city_selected'] == 'Guangzhou') { echo 'selected=selected';} else { echo ''; }?> >Guangzhou</option>
                        <option value="Manila" <?php if($_SESSION['city_selected'] == 'Manila') { echo 'selected=selected';} else { echo ''; }?> >Manila</option>
                        <option value="HongKong" <?php if($_SESSION['city_selected'] == 'HongKong') { echo 'selected=selected';} else { echo ''; }?> >Hong Kong</option>
                        <option value="Tokyo" <?php if($_SESSION['city_selected'] == 'Tokyo') { echo 'selected=selected';} else { echo ''; }?> >Tokyo</option>
                        <option value="Seoul" <?php if($_SESSION['city_selected'] == 'Seoul') { echo 'selected=selected';} else { echo ''; }?> >Seoul</option>
                        <option value="Taipai" <?php if($_SESSION['city_selected'] == 'Taipai') { echo 'selected=selected';} else { echo ''; }?> >Taipai</option>
                        </select></form>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        </div>
```

I'm trying to submit the form and also redirect to a url.  I was wondering if this was possible.  I've tried implementing a jquery $.change event but it didn't fire before the form submit()

if anyone could help, that would be fantastic.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it in php by:
`header('Location: ' . the_url_to_redirect);`

Comment: Could you give me a possible example with the example code?  Dynamic

Comment: Remember header() must be called before any output is sent, you do your staff, then call this function.

Answer (score 0):

where is your submit function?

Can you try like this

```
<select name="city_select" id="city_select" onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

It should work

Comment: onchange="submit();"

works just fine and that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown what your submit function does, but if it does a normal form submission (not AJAX), then you will need to redirect at a later time.

Normally, you would have your form submit normally, and then when the next page loads, that page would set a 'Location' header telling the browser to redirect.

For example, in whatever PHP code runs when the form submits, you will need to redirect by doing this:

```
header('Location', 'http://mysite.com/page-to-redirect-to.php');
```

Comment: action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>"

should explain what it does.  It submits the form with the value contained by the option

Answer (score 0):

All you need is "Jquery Form Plugin"

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm

With this plug-in the form submits to the 'action' address without leaving the page. When it's done you can redirect with the callback function.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#FORM_ID').ajaxForm(function(data) {
            window.location="http://www.REDIRECT_URL.com/"; 
        });                          
    });
</script>
```

If you need this onchange you can use this one :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   

        $('#FORM_ID').ajaxForm(function(data) {
            window.location="http://www.REDIRECT_URL.com/"; 
        });  

        $('#city_select').change(function(){
            $('#FORM_ID').trigger('submit');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Works for a single form submission (#FORM_ID) but as you can see I needed something dynamic.  #OPT_SEL1, #OPT_SEL2, etc for instance.  Not just a single submission.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['city_select'])) {

$_SESSION['city_selected'] = $_POST['city_select'];

if($_POST['city_select'] == "Beijing") {
    header("Location: /city-beijing/");
}
if($_POST['city_select'] == "Shanghai") {
    header("Location: /city-shanghai/");
}
if($_POST['city_select'] == "Guangzhou") {
    header("Location: /city-guangzhou/");
}
if($_POST['city_select'] == "Manila") {
    header("Location: /city-manila/");
}
if($_POST['city_select'] == "HongKong") {
    header("Location: /city-hong-kong/");
}
if($_POST['city_select'] == "Tokyo") {
    header("Location: /city-tokyo/");
}
if($_POST['city_select'] == "Seoul") {
    header("Location: /city-seoul/");
}
if($_POST['city_select'] == "Taipai") {
    header("Location: /city-taipai/");
}

else{

}
```

}

this worked for me :), cheers.